# Gnuplot: How to plot a 45 degree line?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot data from two different years and insert a 45 degree line so you can easily see if the value increased or decreased. X- and Y-axis will be from 0 to 1.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I don't use gnuplot, but a 45-degree slope can be drawn by the simple function y=x.

Comment: Is this `plot [0:1] x` what you you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's actually sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Thor says, 45 degrees can be plotted simply by using `plot x`.

For a more general solution, you can use `tan`.

For example, to plot all lines from 0 degrees to 85 degrees

```
set angles degrees
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
plot x*tan(0), x*tan(5), x*tan(10), x*tan(15), x*tan(20), x*tan(25), x*tan(30), x*tan(35), x*tan(40), x*tan(45), x*tan(50), x*tan(55), x*tan(60), x*tan(65), x*tan(70), x*tan(75), x*tan(80), x*tan(85)
```

[image]